# Which service can I use to upload and distribute audio interviews

Tags: recording

What service can I use to upload audio interviews I recorded whilst on a journey. They vary in length. I recorded interviews with various people from NGOs, and working in the environment area through Asia.

I've fairly disparate content. Some of it is really important and interesting interview, some music snippets, some topical 'podcast'-like elements. I feel that it is important that it doesn't just sit on a disk hidden away, so I need your guy's help.

Comment: What is your target audience for the interviews? This dictates where you upload to.

Comment: My target audience is the blog community blogging about these topics, and their readers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should merge the audio into a "video" then put it on youtube. With youtube your audience gets the accessibility and the streaming to their pc (or android) without worries of having the correct media player installed.

You don't need to actually make a video - it can be still shots or just a fixed screen describing the contents. I'm just about at this point with my music - I'm considering making my songs into videos just so they can be "found" on youtube.

I downloaded a program called Avidemux which I hope I can use. It's fairly basic but to me basic video stuff is complex (until I learn it!!!)

There is also soundcloud that several sites (including this site) will automatically stream like a youtube video but it's just for audio.